# How to restore default Unity

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz

I was messing around with Compiz Settings Manager and result of that is that I cant see my panel bar, cant use alt+tab or start button. Is there a way to restore default Ubuntu environment? I will be grateful for your help

Comment: Difference is that i have cairo dock and its running fine. It`s only way i can run programs like firefox. But i can`t move, minimalize, resize program windows.

Comment: Yes, unable control windows is a common symptom of failed compiz plugins. You need to reenable them via compizconfig settings manager as shown in the duplicate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In terminal, type in `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` to completely reinstall back to defaults.

To remove all compiz settings type `rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1` in terminal, then logout and back in.

Comment: still nothing...i think that`s something with compiz. Maybe i shoul remove compiz completly and the reinstall ubuntu-desktop. What do you think?

Comment: @LudwigSupraphonic I added a second command in my answer to specifically delete all compiz settings.  New default settings will be created when you log back in.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can install "Unity Tweak Tool" and set the default settings. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: Had wired terminal and windows behavior. removing `~/.config/compiz-1` wasn't the solution. But hitting the `restore default` button in the `unity-tweak-tool` brought my Unity back to normal behavior. THX

Comment: @Tik0 I am trying it now, In unity-tweak-tool, there is one 'restore default' button in each and every menu.. which button do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following, open terminal and type:

```
unity-reset
```

Alternatively:

```
setsid unity
```

But, If you can't get to the terminal cause your start buttons doesn't work you can always (this only works if you have a folder on the desktop) open the folder then go to 'computer>usr>share>applications' look for terminal inside the folder and click to open, then enter either of the above commands in the terminal.

Comment: The command `unity-reset` does not exist on 16.04.